# (Variables) Premature end of file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Hi I am new in XSLT and at the moment I try to catch two variables, one cames out of the Database and the outher is my NULL Variable for my own Head-controlled loop process. I havent found any thing here that helped me with that problem so Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output media-type="text/xml" method="xml"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:variable name="Counter" select="document('context:Counter')"></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="Counted">
                <xsl:value-of>0</xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:variable>
            <Counter>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Counter"></xsl:value-of>
            </Counter>
            <Counted>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Counted"></xsl:value-of>
            </Counted>
            <xsl:if test="not($Counted = $Counter)">
                <xsl:processing-instruction name="ConditionState">
                    2000
                </xsl:processing-instruction>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$Counted = $Counter">
                <xsl:processing-instruction name="ConditionState">
                    2001
                </xsl:processing-instruction>
            </xsl:if>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want that the `ConditionState` is 2000 on not equals and 2001 on equals for my Condition. The problem is he jumped out of the Code and I don't know why or where... 
Here is my Error:

```
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.
```

I hoped some one here can help me with that.

Comment: For loading document, use document('file.etxn'), then variable declaration for loading document is like <xsl:variable name="Counter" select="document('File.xml')"/>. Try with this. Here proper document name (missing extension of document) required.

Comment: A `SAXParseException` is usually from the XML parser so either your primary XML input or your secondary one you are trying to load with the `document` function or the XSLT code is not complete. How/where do you map `'context:Counter'` to your database?

Comment: I want to build it for a dynamic process. The interpreter generates a randomly named XML file with the content of the previously executed XSLT. Is there no possibility to integrate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this post, here is my solve:

my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xe.source ../Data/DBO_Output.xml#root?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output media-type="text/xml" method="xml"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:variable name="Counter">
                <xsl:value-of select="./root"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="Counted" select="0">
            </xsl:variable>
            <Counter>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Counter"></xsl:value-of>
            </Counter>
            <Counted>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Counted"></xsl:value-of>
            </Counted>
            <xsl:if test="$Counter &gt;= $Counted">
                <xsl:processing-instruction name="ConditionState">
                    2000
                </xsl:processing-instruction>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="not($Counter &gt;= $Counted) or $Counter = $Counted">
                <xsl:processing-instruction name="ConditionState">
                    2001
                </xsl:processing-instruction>
            </xsl:if>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I write the Database data in an external xml file and just read that one to get the data for my transformation.